# Prestashop 1.7 using Import csv function programmatically

Tags: php, csv, prestashop-1.7

I state that I'm not familiar with Prestashop and I'm using version 1.7.6.
I'm trying to understand how I could use the import function from csv file without using of user interface.
I tried to look for documentation on a possible web api but I found nothing.

What I'd like to accomplish is the following scenario:
I have two web applications on the same server
/my_webapp
/my_prestashop

By "my_webapp" I receive a csv file, process it and produce a new csv file.
Now continuing  running the process in "my_webapp", I would like to instantiate the ambient of the prestashop application to invoke the import csv function by passing it the new file just created.

Searching the web I found some sample code but, trying to use and adapt it, I am not making it work.
For example, on “my_webapp” folder I just create a “myimport.php” file and call it with two GET parameters.
The following is the call:

```
localhost/my_webapp/myimport.php?csv=prod.csv&limit=5
```

note: the file “prod.csv” is on
"path to admin folder"/import

Content of “myimport.php” file:

```
<?php
$rootPrestashop = '/var/www/html/my_prestashop”;
define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', $rootPrestashop.'/admin_shop'); //not sure if this instruction is needed 
$pathConfig = $rootPrestashop.'/config/config.inc.php';
$initConfig = $rootPrestashop.'/init.php'; 

require_once($pathConfig);
require_once($initConfig); //this line throw an error and then I can't test the others!

$importCtrl = new AdminImportControllerCore();
$crossSteps = array();
$limit = $_GET["limit"];
$importCtrl->productImport(false, $limit, $crossSteps, true, 0);
```

This is what I’m trying to do, but I failed to initialize the environment.
Maybe I’m on the wrong way and there’s a better way.
I ask if anyone can help me understand if I can carry out this process and what would be the correct way.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) {
    define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', __DIR__);
}
include _PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/config.inc.php';

if (!Context::getContext()->employee->isLoggedBack()) {
    Tools::redirectAdmin(Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink('AdminLogin'));
}
```